# Tensor Product proof

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, tensor-products

I have to prove something for my matrix-algebra course. it's the following proof:

I have to prove that $A\otimes B$ is invertible, if and only if $B\otimes B$ is invertible.

Please explain this in simple language, I'm only a first year econometrics student.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ square matrices?

Comment: Could be, it's not given..

Comment: This might help give you some intuition: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/msnarski/tensors1.PDF

Comment: I think $B\otimes B$ should be corrected to $B\otimes A$. See,[Invertibility of a Kronecker Product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301315/invertibility-of-a-kronecker-product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong. Take the zero matrix as $A$ and for $B$ any invertible matrix. Then the Kronecker-product of $B$ with itself is invertible with inverse $B^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$ (can be proven by matrix multiplication), but $A \otimes B$ is zero, and therefore not invertible.